# How to connect Flask REST API to HTML page

Tags: python, api, flask

I have created an REST-API using flask so now , I don't know how to connect it with HTML page .
Hear is my app.py code of rest-api
from blocklist import blocklist
import re
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

```
    import redis

    from db import db
    from jwt import PyJWKClient
    from resources.user import UserRegister, User, UserLogin, TokenRefresh, UserLogout
    from resources.item import Item, ItemList
    from resources.store import Store, StoreList

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///data.db"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    app.config["PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS"] = True
    app.config["JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED"] = True


   app.secret_key = "jose"

   api = Api(app)


   @app.before_first_request
     def create_tables():
         db.create_all()


    jwt = JWTManager(app)  # not creating an auth

    jwt_redis_blocklist = redis.StrictRedis(
        host="localhost", port=5000, decode_responses=True
     )


    @jwt.expired_token_loader
    def check_if_token_is_revoked(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        jti = jwt_payload["jti"]
        token_in_redis = jwt_redis_blocklist.get(jti)
        return token_in_redis is not None

    @jwt.token_in_blocklist_loader
   def check_if_token_in_blacklist(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
        return jwt_payload["jti"] in blocklist


    api.add_resource(Store, "/store/<string:name>")
    api.add_resource(StoreList, "/stores")
    api.add_resource(Item, "/item/<string:name>")
    api.add_resource(ItemList, "/items")
    api.add_resource(UserRegister, "/register")
    api.add_resource(User, "/user/<int:user_id>")
    api.add_resource(UserLogin, "/login")
    api.add_resource(UserLogout, "/logout")

    api.add_resource(TokenRefresh, "/refresh")

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       db.init_app(app)
       app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

I have no idea how do I fetch data from API and show it to HTML page

Answer (score 1):

```
@app.route("/")
def page_home():
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    return flask.render_template('home.html')
```

like above you can render the html file